# MySQL: Create children for every parent in mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, treeview, parent

how do I create a query from two tables where each child is assigned to its parents.

1 Table `table_one`

```
+---+------------+-------------+---------+
|id |  prj_id    |   name      | status  |
+---+------------+-------------+---------+
| 1 | 808361     | projectOne  | open    |
| 2 | 808365     | projectTwo  | close   |
| 3 | 808370     | projectThree| open    |
+---+------------+-------------+---------+
```

2 Table `table_two`

```
+---+------------+---------+
|id |  prj_id    |   task  |
+---+------------+---------+
| 1 | 808361     | java    |
| 2 | 808365     | c++     |
| 3 | 808365     | python  |
| 4 | 808370     | java    |
| 5 | 808370     | c++     |
| 6 | 808370     | python  |  
+---+------------+---------+
```

My MySQL queries:

```
SELECT tt.prj_id, tt.taks, to.status
FROM table_two tt
INNER JOIN table_one to ON to.prj_id = tt.prj_id
```

Result to the MySQL query:

```
+---+------------+---------+--------+
|id |  prj_id    |   task  | status |
+---+------------+---------+--------+
| 1 | 808361     | java    | open   |
| 2 | 808365     | c++     | close  |
| 3 | 808365     | python  | close  |
| 4 | 808370     | java    | open   |
| 5 | 808370     | c++     | open   |
| 6 | 808370     | python  | open   | 
+---+------------+---------+--------+
```

Now I would like to come to the following result and I just do not know how to continue

My desired output:

```
+---+------------+---------+--------+
|id |  prj_id    |   task  | status | 
+---+------------+---------+--------+
| 1 | 808361     | -       | -      |  
| 2 | 808361     | java    | open   |   
| 3 | 808365     | -       | -      |   
| 4 | 808365     | c++     | close  |   
| 5 | 808365     | python  | close  |   
| 6 | 808370     | -       | -      |   
| 7 | 808370     | java    | open   |   
| 8 | 808370     | c++     | open   |   
| 9 | 808370     | python  | open   |   
+---+------------+---------+--------+
```

Or can I somehow solve the issue with Python or something.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: What does the `parent_id` represent here? Where is it taken from?

Comment: Why do you want empty rows ?

Comment: The parent_id was just fictional. I removed them because I do not need them. The empty rows

Comment: Why do you need NULL values for each parent_id in your desired result. [The places you have put a - ]